# Installing tile over hardiboard

Tags: ceramic-tile

I'm using hardi backer board under my tile, over a wood subfloor, and I will be using thinset between the hardiboard and the subfloor; can I tile immediately after installing the hardiboard?

Comment: Yes! Not a problem.

Comment: why didn't you screw the hardi-backer down to the subfloor?  How thick of a bead did you use under the hardi-backer?

Comment: I've actually never seen hardibacker set in thinset. It's ALWAYS screwed down, and I have seen dozens and dozens of bathroom installs.
I would assume it'd be fine though. Personally I'd wait 'till it's set. If you walk and kneel around on it immediately it will shift and not set evenly.

Comment: @speedy-petey, I will be screwing it down, however the instructions on hardi's website states to lay it in thinset, then screw it down, but it doesn't state when it can be walked on.

Comment: I'd still give it time to set up. I would not walk on it for at least a couple of hours. It's just insurance that it will set properly.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey, I believe they suggest laying it on thinset (as well as screwing) so the thinset fills any voids in the sub-floor. This way you don't get flex in the hardibard when you have a small low spot in the floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with someone at Home Depot, and they made a good point - You're screwing it down on top of the thinset, and therefore you're already on top of the board. The more important part is to let the thinset on the seams (along with the tape) set up for a while (a few hours) before tiling. We did just that, and so far so good - the tiles went down fairly smoothly, though I still need to grout.